# Custom UIStoryboardSegue - UIViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations never call

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a problem creating a custom segue: I'm overriding the "perform()" method as follows

```
override func perform() {
    if !isBack {
        self.destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, 0, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.height)
        self.sourceViewController.view.addSubview(self.destinationViewController.view)
        self.sourceViewController.addChildViewController(self.destinationViewController)
        print("Source: \(self.sourceViewController) ---> Destination: \(self.destinationViewController)")
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.width, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (bolean) -> Void in
                print("Animation Completed")
        })

    }else{
        print("Source: \(self.sourceViewController) ---> Destination: \(self.destinationViewController)")
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, 0, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (bolean) -> Void in
                print("Animation Completed")

                self.sourceViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
```

Everything runs fine but, at this point, the rotation method in "destinationViewController" are not being called. So, if I lock "sourceViewController" to portrait mode while leaving the "destinationViewController" unlocked the latter doesn't rotate.

Assuming the problem resides in this line:
`self.sourceViewController.view.addSubview(self.destinationViewController.view)`
how should I change the code to fix the rotation?

Comment: Other than printing out the log messages, what does this custom segue do that a standard `push` segue doesn't do? AFAICT, this is sliding the destination view controller in from the right when navigating to it, and the opposite when navigating back.

Comment: OK this is only an example of animation, and if i want create a most complex animation of push or modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guy i have find the solution like this.

```
override func perform() {
    if !isBack {
        self.destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, 0, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.width, self.sourceViewController.view.frame.height)

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(self.destinationViewController.view, aboveSubview: self.sourceViewController.view)

        print("Source: \(self.sourceViewController) ---> Destination: \(self.destinationViewController)")
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.width, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (bolean) -> Void in
                print("Animazione Terminata")
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })

    }else{
        print("Indietro Source: \(self.sourceViewController) ---> Destination: \(self.destinationViewController)")

        let snapshot = self.sourceViewController.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
        snapshot.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, snapshot.frame.size.width, snapshot.frame.size.height)
        self.destinationViewController.view.addSubview(snapshot)
        self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                snapshot.frame = CGRectMake(self.destinationViewController.view.frame.width, 0, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.width, self.destinationViewController.view.frame.height)
                }, completion: { (bolean) -> Void in
                    print("Animazione Terminata")
                    snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

i have understand that the UIStoryboar in the end doing the same operation like a presentation. So before you have to create the animation, then present. And when you need to dismiss before get a snapshot of screen dismiss source VC without animation (add snap in destination VC before dismiss) and in the end animate the snap.

tnx and buy.

sorry for my bad english but talk is chip i show the code.

Edit: There is a litle imprecision in my code. For prevent problem of animation simply set inside the present o dismiss complanion your animation.